# Conditions that a module has a unique largest divisible submodule.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

Kaplansky in Theorem 8 of [This paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjE08vqi4_ZAhXMDuwKHeGYDxEQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Ftran%2F1952-072-02%2FS0002-9947-1952-0046349-0%2FS0002-9947-1952-0046349-0.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3RZnj70QbufblXq3lWbyqk) state that, "any module $M$ over a Dedekind ring possesses a unique largest divisibel submodule $D$; $M=D\oplus E$ where $E$ has no divisible submodules."

Is there weaker conditions (than Dedekind domain which is very strong) on a ring such that this Theorem be still true? Thanks a lot.